# Indexing 2d array bar with another 2d array foo where foo contains row indices for corresponding columns of bar

Tags: python, numpy

This is best explained with an example..

```
foo = np.array([
    [0,0],
    [0,1],
    [1,0],
    [1,1]
])

bar = np.array([
    [10,12],
    [5,11]
])

desired = np.stack((bar[:, 0][foo[:, 0]], bar[:, 1][foo[:, 1]]), axis = 1)
array([[10, 12],
       [10, 11],
       [ 5, 12],
       [ 5, 11]])
```

So, if you consider the first column of foo `[0, 0, 1, 1]` and you use those indices to select elements from the first column of bar `[10, 5]`, you get the first column of my desired result `[10, 10, 5, 5]`.

The problem is, I'm having trouble figuring out how to generalize this to support an unknown number of rows and columns for foo and bar (and speed is important to me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use integer-indexing with `foo` for the row-indexing and a ranged array ranging over the extent of `foo` for the column-indexing -

```
bar[foo,np.arange(foo.shape[1])]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import numpy as np

def proc(foo, bar):
    ncol = bar.shape[-1]
    coloffset = np.arange(ncol)
    idx = (foo * ncol + coloffset).ravel()
    return bar.ravel()[idx].reshape(foo.shape)
```

In short:

1. it first calculates the flatten index from `foo` (i.e. the `idx` variable),
2. use it to access the elements in `bar`, then
3. reshape it to the intended shape.

The `.ravel()` and `.reshape(...)` operations are relatively cheap because they don't have to allocate memory for a new array.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the desired array by using foo to index bar, just like you explained. The shortest way to do that that I can come up with is this:

```
np.array([[bar[foo[j][i]][i] for i in range(2)] for j in range(4)])
```

If the sizes of the arrays are fixed you can leave it like this, otherwise you have to change it in the ranges of the for loops as well.

Comment: Python for loops are slow. Can you devise a solution without them?

Comment: Any matrix has to be constituted element by element, unless you're using parallel processing, which can be achieved with halide or cuda. But I don't think this can be done in python